# Can't find libunistring when building guile from nonstandard location

Tags: configure, guile

I'm trying to build Guile 2.2.

I've installed libunistring to `/path/to/libunistring`.

When I run

```
./configure --with-libunistring-prefix=/path/to/libunistring/
```

it fails, because it can't find libunistring.

```
configure:15954: checking for libunistring
configure:15976: gcc -std=gnu11 -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c  -lunistring >&5
conftest.c:158:21: fatal error: uniconv.h: No such file or directory
 #include <uniconv.h>
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

The configure script is searching for `/path/to/libunistring/lib64/`. I believe you have only `/path/to/libunistring/lib/`.

```
% ln -s /path/to/libunistring/lib /path/to/libunistring/lib64
```